# Unet architecture on Carvana dataset

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, image-segmentation, kaggle

I have followed [zhixuhao's](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet) unet implementation and another implementation from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/srinesh/unet-implementation-of-caravana-kernel).

Both models are not that much different from each other, except the fact that former has a few extra layers and thus almost 30 million more parameters.

My problem is that I am not able to get either of the models to perform good (I mean -800 something loss in both models), in terms of binary_crossentropy loss and accuracy or dice_coef as metric.Please help me find where am I going wrong.
here are some of my suspicions:

1) One intresting thing I noticed, dice_coef reaches upto 1.9 within a single epoch ( which shouldn't be possible as it should be less than 1). So here is the dice_coeff function from the kaggle link

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=0):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection=K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return(2. * intersection + smooth) / ((K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f)) + smooth)
```

2) `flow_from_directory()` function given in keras doesn't read .gif files by default (mask image is in .gif format). So I followed [this advice](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3946#issuecomment-326825121) and added gif in `keras/preprocessing/image.py`. And then while reading the image through `flow_from_directory()` I gave `color_mode = 'grayscale'` so that target image has 1 channel since UNet architecture last layer was 1 channel output. If i read image by my own through `skimage.io.imread()` , gif image is of size `(1024, 1024)`, i.e. 1 channel.

3) I also thought that maybe image augmentations were responsible.I have used mainly the default augmentations from [keras](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). Here is whole image reading and augmentation part

```
input_shape = (1024, 1024, 3)
batch_size = 4
# we create two instances with the same arguments
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=90,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
seed = 1

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'Carvana/train',
    target_size = (input_shape[0], input_shape[1]),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'Carvana/train_masks',
    target_size = (input_shape[0], input_shape[1]),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

model2 = unet(input_shape)
model2.fit_generator(
    train_generator,    
    steps_per_epoch=50,
    epochs=2)
```

the training output is

```
Found 5088 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 5088 images belonging to 1 classes.
Epoch 1/2
50/50 [==============================] - 66s 1s/step - loss: -724.1043 - dice_coef: 1.8661
Epoch 2/2
50/50 [==============================] - 64s 1s/step - loss: -829.2828 - dice_coef: 1.9626
```

finally here is the whole network from [this kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/srinesh/unet-implementation-of-caravana-kernel), my only modification is changed input to `channel-last` and `axis = 3` from `axis = 1` in concatenation layers

```
def unet(input_shape):
    input_ = Input(input_shape)
    conv0 = Conv2D(8, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(input_)
    conv0 = Conv2D(8, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv0)
    pool0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv0)

    conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool0)
    conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv5))
    merge6 = Concatenate(axis = 3)([conv4,up6])
    conv6 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = Concatenate(axis = 3)([conv3,up7])
    conv7 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(32, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = Concatenate(axis = 3)([conv2,up8])
    conv8 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(16, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = Concatenate(axis = 3)([conv1,up9])
    conv9 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)

    up10 = Conv2D(16, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv9))

    conv10 = Conv2D(8, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(up10)
    conv11 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv10)

    model = Model(input = input_, outputs = conv11)

    model.compile(optimizer= Adam(lr=0.0005), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[dice_coef])

    return model
```

Finally here is me testing only model's mask output on the 1st image in training dataset

```
pic = cv2.resize(io.imread('Carvana/train/train/0cdf5b5d0ce1_01.jpg'), input_shape[:2])
pic = pic.reshape(1, input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2])
res = model2.predict(pic)
print(res[0].shape)
res = np.array(res[0])
r = res * 200
g = res * 1
b = res * 70
res = np.concatenate((r, g, b), axis = 2)
io.imshow(res)
```

I am sorry for such a long post, but I am unable to pin point exact error that I have committed. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: many things could be going wrong. First off, point number 2: Caravana dataset has coloured images so **3 channels, not 1**. The UNET's output has only 1 class because it predicts car/no car.

As a tip, a good way to debug usually is to call the generator (`next(train_generator(...))`) and check what the network will be getting.

Comment: input images are colored, so i've read them in 3 channels, but masks are binary, thats why i thought to use grayscale, yes usually segmentation has a mask with n channels for n objects, but here only car and background are the 2 classes

`next(train_generator)` is useful, but i already know the shape expected from `model.summary()`

Comment: use `next(train_generator)`to make sure your data is in the right shape not the model. Also, are you scaling or normalizing your data?

Comment: I am only resizing , i was normalizing and scaling earlier but then removed them for testing , and yes I have checked the shape of both input and target data

Comment: ok then if the data supplied to the net is good (not just dimensions, also values vs masks), the net looks fine and the loss as well then I am not sure how to help! I would also scrap the `flow_from_directory` and try to write my own generator to make sure it behaves as expected (not long to do). Could you try the `class_mode='binary'` as parameter as well?